# Overriding DisplayFormat(DataFormatString)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, viewmodel, data-annotations

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass
{
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.00}")]
    public virtual decimal Value
    {
        get { return 1.23456m; }
    }
}

public class MyDerivedClassA : MyBaseClass
{
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.0}")]
    public override decimal Value
    {
        get { return 9.87654m; }
    }
}

...

public class MyDerivedClassZ : MyBaseClass
{
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.000}")]
    public override decimal Value
    {
        get { return 7.654321m; }
    }
}
```

-

```
@model MyBaseClass

@Html.DisplayFor(m => @Model.Value)
```

When passing each of the to object above into the razor view I expected to get...

- 1.23
- 9.8

However the DisplayFormat does not seem to override along with the property, instead I get...

- 1.23
- 9.87

Does anyone know how to get around this?

EDIT:
Sorry, wasn't clear. If I have n*`Derived Classes` how can I solve the problem in a way that won't involve a new file for each and every type?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom display template (`~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/MyDerivedClass.cshtml`):

```
@model MyDerivedClass           
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Value)
```

and then inside your main `Index.cshtml` view:

```
@model MyBaseClass
@Html.DisplayForModel()
```